# Show $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=9$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]=\lbrace x+y\sqrt{5}i\mid x,y\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace.$ Show that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$ with $|\alpha|=9$, then $\alpha$ is prime.

My attempt: Suppose $\alpha |[ (x+y\sqrt{5}i)(a+b\sqrt{5}i)]$ where $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $(x+y\sqrt{5}i)(a+b\sqrt{5}i)=\alpha (c+d\sqrt{5}i)$. Take its conjugate,we obtain $(x-y\sqrt{5}i)(a-b\sqrt{5}i)=\bar{\alpha}(c-d\sqrt{5}i)$. Multiply the two equations, we get $(x^2+5y^2)(a^2+5b^2)=3(c^2+5d^2)$.

Then from here how we proceed?

EDIT: How we show that $\gcd(9,6+3\sqrt{5}i)$ does not exist?

Comment: Use norm $N(a+b\sqrt(5)i)=a^2+5b^2$. You can easily check $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$

Comment: Since, according to the definitions found in many books, $3$ is *not* prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, could you please make explicit what definition of *prime* you're using?

Comment: @egreg: If $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$, then either $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: @Idonknow Then the statement you want to prove is false: $3$ divides $(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})$ but doesn't divide either factor. Actually the correct statement is “if $|\alpha|=9$ then $\alpha$ is not prime”.

Comment: How to show the gcd of two elements in this set does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false, assuming that the definition of prime is

> an element $p$ in a domain $D$ is prime if $p\ne0$, $p$ is not invertible and, for all $a,b\in D$, if $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Indeed, if $|\alpha|=9$, then the possibilities are $\alpha=3$, $\alpha=2+\sqrt{-5}$ or $\alpha=2-\sqrt{-5}$ (and opposite elements thereof). None of these elements is prime, because none of the three elements divides the other two, but each of them divides $9=3\cdot 3=(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})$.

The true statement is “*if $|\alpha|=9$ then $\alpha$ is irreducible but not prime*”

Answer (score -1):

Let $\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $\beta \gamma=\alpha$.  Then $N(\beta)N(\gamma)=N(\alpha)=9$.  Therefore, either $\beta$ or $\gamma$ is a unit or $N(\beta)=N(\gamma)=3$.  This implies $x^2+5y^2=3$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.  If $y\neq0$, it is clear the left-hand-side is greater than 3, so $y=0$.  Then we're looking for $x^2=3$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore any pair of divisors of $\alpha$ contains a unit.

Comment: Well, it remains to show that in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ every irreducible element is prime and this does not really hold.

Comment: Can you explain how will this leads to $\alpha$ is a prime?

Comment: As already hinted by *user* in his comment above, it doesn't @Idonknow : here, irreducible isn't the same as prime, which hardly surprises since, as noted by egreg, your claim is false.